# How do I set the Scala compiler to use a plugin when I build using Maven?

Tags: scala, maven

So I have a Maven project with two submodules. The first is the compiler plugin itself, which gets compiled as I expect it to.

The second submodule is some example code that I want to compiler with the previously built compiler plugin.

So I have this in the pom file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <sourceDir>.</sourceDir>
    <!--jvmArgs>
      <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
      <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
    </jvmArgs-->
    <args>
      <arg>-Xplugin:../plugin/target/plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</arg>
    </args>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Which based on what I could read about it, should give the right arguments to the compiler, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

*Edit*: As suggested, I tried to use the *compilerPlugins* tag, so the relevant area became:

```
<configuration>
<sourceDir>.</sourceDir>
  <compilerPlugins>
    <compilerPlugin>
      <groupId>*groupid*</groupId>
      <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </compilerPlugin>
  </compilerPlugins>
</configuration>
```

And that did indeed work, unfortunately it now produces this error:

Unable to find resource '*groupid*:plugin:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT' in repository scala-tools.org (http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases)

Which is quite understandable, as it isn't there.

I tried to add it as a dependency to the dependencies list, but that didn't change anything.

*final edit*:

executing:

```
mvn clean install
```

fixed it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't it work using the compilerPlugin configuration to set the artifact?

http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerPlugins

**Update**: It's basically an artifact like a dependency. You will add your compiler plugin as artifact inside it:

```
<compilerPlugins>
  <compilerPlugin>
    <groupId>_your plugins groupId_</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</groupId>
  </compilerPlugin>
</compilerPlugins>
```

Comment: Thats likely it, but I am new to maven. Do you know what 
org_scala_tools_maven.BasicArtifact[] means?

Comment: Thanks, now it figured out that it was needed. Unfortunately it attempts to download it. How do I tell it not to?